# How to secure apache camel proxy service?

Tags: java, web-services, cxf, apache-camel

I am new to apache camel. I am right now trying the camel-example-cxf-proxy example provided in the apache camel bundle. I am able to compile and run it. Now i want to secure this proxy service but i am not able to figure out how to proceed. Or in Simple terms i want to implement AUTHENTICATION in this proxy service project.

Looking forward to your solutions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean secure it? Please add more detail on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I want to add security to the proxy wsdl. If a user hits this proxy service, he should pass username and password and then he should get redirected to the original service endpoint.

Comment: You can add a jetty handler to CXF endpoint to enable the basic authentication. http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jetty-configuration.html

Comment: You can have a look to the [apache-shiro](http://shiro.apache.org) project. You can manage the authentication and the authorization just with a simple config file (for starting).